# Unable to properly set environment variable LD_PRELOAD in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write an script that will execute the following commands:

```
${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -static myinit.c -o myinit
cd initramfs
fakeroot # this is pure magic (it allows us to pretend to be root)
mkdir -p dev
mknod dev/console c 5 1
chown root init
find . | cpio -H newc -o > ../initramfs.cpio # <-- this is the actual initramfs
exit # leave the fakeroot shell
cd ..
```

As of now I have to do this manually 200 times a day. So I guess it can be converted into an scipt which will automate the process.  follwoing other answers in this forum what I tried is this:

**updated code**

```
    #!/bin/bash

 LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib64/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-tcp.so" printenv "LD_PRELOAD" libfakeroot-tcp.so

 printenv "LD_PRELOAD"

     printenv "LD_PRELOAD"


    arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static echotest.c -o init
        cp init initramfs
        cd initramfs
        fakeroot
        mkdir -p dev
        mknod dev/console c 5 1
        chown root init
        find . | cpio -H newc -o > ../initramfs.cpio
        exit
        cd ..
```

I saved this in test.sh , and made this file executable.  And here is the output I am getting:

**updated output**

```
/usr/lib64/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-tcp.so
libfakeroot-tcp.so
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-tcp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-tcp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-tcp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-tcp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-tcp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
fakeroot: FAKEROOTKEY set to 39730
fakeroot: nested operation not yet supported
1289 blocks
```

I am getting the expected file initramfs.cpio , but why these errors?

Comment: Is your library setuid? Try making it setgid with `chmod g+s libfakeroot-tcp.so`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your comment. But do you think this error is going to affect the output file initramfs.cpio

Comment: @MarkSetchell [root@xilinx /]# chmod g+s /usr/lib64/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-tcp.so   but even then same errors coming.

Comment: Have you tried putting the full path to the library when setting LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated my code and the output based on your suggestions, but still smae issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib64/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-tcp.so" printenv "LD_PRELOAD" libfakeroot-tcp.so
```

that sets the LD_PRELOAD variable **only** for the duration of the printenv command. Try:

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib64/libfakeroot/libfakeroot-tcp.so"

arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static echotest.c -o init
...
```

Comment: This gives:  libfakeroot: FAKEROOTKEY not defined in environment ..in addition to other errors

Comment: Do you need to `export FAKEROOTKEY=some_value` ?